# gradle script, What’s difference between direct dsl and called by a custom function of “apply from:”

Tags: gradle, apply

First, there are some common scripts deployed in private maven repo:

http://domain/repo/com/d/build/script/java-project/1.0/java-project-1.0.gradle

http://domain/repo/com/d/build/script/maven/1.0/maven-1.0.gradle

In the target project, build.gradle

```
subprojects {
  apply from: 'http://domain/repo/com/d/build/script/java-project/1.0/java-project-1.0.gradle'
  apply from: 'http://domain/repo/com/d/build/script/maven/1.0/maven-1.0.gradle'
}
```

**it's OK!**

but,

```
ext.applyScript = { script, version ->
  apply from: "http://domain/repo/com/d/build/script/${script}/${version}/${script}-${version}.gradle"
}

subprojects {
  applyScript('java-project', '1.0')
  applyScript('maven', '1.0')
}
```

**it will fail**, with message:

"Error:Cannot add task ':javadocJar' as a task with that name already exists."

task ':javadocJar' is defined in script 'java-project-1.0.gradle'
and we have several sub projects.

why ?

BTW: anyone can give me a lead of source location of "apply from:"?

It's hard to location it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is that in the latte case you are applying the scripts multiple times to the same root project.**

How is that possible? It is quite interesting and a little bit tricky:

1. you are defining `applyScript` as a Closure on the extension container `ext` of the current Gradle project,
2. generally the `apply from: ...` is handled as a method call `apply(Map)` on the `org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware` interface which is one of the super interfaces of the `org.gradle.api.Project` interface

   - this means every time you write `apply ...` you are calling the `apply` method on the current Gradle project (the one where the `apply ...` is specified)
3. as you defined the `apply ...` as part of the closure, the standard delegation applies

   - it is semantically the same as `this.apply ...`
   - `this` by default points to the enclosing class/object which is the root project (here it cannot be anything else)

**So even if it looks like you are applying the 2 scripts to all the subprojects, you are actually applying the 2 scripts N times to the root project (N is the number of subprojects).**

**What you need  to do is to change the delegate to the correct `Project` instance.**:

1. you can do it very easily by adding one additional argument to the closure and explicitly calling the apply method on that argument:

   ```
   ext.applyScript = { project, script, version ->
       project.apply from: "..."
   }

   subprojects {
       applyScript(it, 'java-project', '1.0')
       applyScript(it, 'maven', '1.0')
   }
   ```
2. or you can set the delegate explicitly:

   ```
   ext.applyScript = { script, version ->
       apply from: "..."
   }

   subprojects {
       applyScript.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
       applyScript.delegate = it

       applyScript('java-project', '1.0')
       applyScript('maven', '1.0')
   }
   ```